# Como pegar o id da view caso tenha asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte situação, no meu _Layout eu estou verificando:

```
@{
    var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    var view = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
 }
```

Eu envio esta informação para o controller para que após trocar o idioma da página eu possa voltar para a mesma.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AlteraIdioma", "Home" , new{LinguagemAbreviada="pt", NomeControler = @controller, NomeView= @view })" >
    <img src="~/ContentAdmin/dist/img/brasil-160x160.png" id="pt" class="user-image" alt="brasil">
    <span class="hidden-xs">-</span>
</a>
```

Quero saber como eu posso pegar o  “Id” caso tenha.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil pegar a url completa?

Comment: pode tentar utilizar viewBag

Comment: @EduardoSampaio, eu precisava de um exemplo, agradeço

Answer (score 1):

A solução:
Seguindo como referência `RoutConfig`

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Ficou desta forma na view:

```
@{
    var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    var view = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    var id = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];  
 }
```

Estou enviando os dados para o controller assim:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AlteraIdioma", "Home" , new{LinguagemAbreviada="pt", NomeControler = @controller, NomeView= @view, IdPagina=@id })" >
    <img src="~/ContentAdmin/dist/img/brasil-160x160.png" id="pt" class="user-image" alt="brasil">
    <span class="hidden-xs">-</span>
</a>
```

Recebo os dados:

```
public ActionResult AlteraIdioma(string LinguagemAbreviada, string NomeControler, string NomeView, string IdPagina)
```

Redirecionar para a mesma página:

```
return RedirectToAction(NomeView, NomeControler, new { id=IdPagina});
```